# How do I set OpenNMS to have two types of Node Down events with different severities?

Tags: network-monitoring, opennms, network-management

For example, I have laptops in one subnet which keep turning on and off so if a node on that subnet went down I'd class that as an intermediate incident.

However, on another subnet there are critical servers which if one went down I'd class as a major incident.

How can I get OpenNMS to treat it separately, preferably by different events but different alarms would be a viable option?

OpenNMS version: 20.0.1

Java version: 1.8.0_131

Java SE Runtime Environment: 1.8.0_131-b11

Java HotSpot 64-Bit Server VM: 25.131-b11, mixed mode

Operating system: Windows Server 2016

PostgreSQL version: 9.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already solved on this forum.

http://ask.opennms.eu/?qa=1196/opennms-have-types-node-down-events-with-different-severities&show=1210#a1210